# Are nested parentheses in the FROM clause valid Oracle SQL syntax?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Does this query use correct Oracle syntax?

```
select * from ( ( ( dual a) ) ) where a.dummy = 'X';
```

It works in 11g and 12c but is it truly valid syntax?  Or is this is just a compiler "mistake" that might be fixed in the future, causing the code the fail?

I doubt this is the correct syntax for the following reasons:

1. It doesn't seem to do anything other than add extra parentheses.  Expressions like ((1+2)*3) can obviously benefit from nested parentheses but I don't see how they would ever help the FROM clause.  And when I look at the above query the alias "a" looks out of scope.
2. I cannot find a valid path for this syntax in the [SQL Language Reference syntax diagrams](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDDCHGF).  On the other hand, it's easy to see how nested parentheses are permitted for [expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions003.htm#SQLRF52070), [conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions010.htm#SQLRF52162),
   and [subqueries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55225).  Expressions, conditions, and subqueries are recursive and can contain parentheses, but a join clause is not recursive.

I worry about this because there have been similar cases where invalid syntax worked in one release and then failed in the next.  For example: `select (select count(*) from (select * from scott.emp where ename = dual.dummy)) from dual;`.  That query worked in 10.2.0.1.0 but stopped working in later versions because [table references are scoped to only one level deep](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932).

The original query has a bad style but it's not worth changing our production queries unless there is a real problem with it.

Is the query invalid?  Or is there some legitimate reason for that syntax, or is there some path in the syntax diagrams I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

It is legal syntax to use parenthesis in a *join clause* in a `FROM`, and the parentheses *do* have an effect.

Consider this query:

```
WITH table_a AS ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30),
     table_b as ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20),
     table_c AS ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT a.id, b.id, c.id
FROM   table_a a left join ( table_b b inner join table_c c ON c.id = b.id ) ON b.id = a.id 
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

The parenthesis allow you to do an inner join of tables `b` and `c` and then outer join that to `a`.

Without the parenthesis, trying to express that as a left join would be impossible.  You either wouldn't get rows 11-30 from table `a` or else rows 11-20 of table `c` would be `null`s (depending on how you tried to do it).

Note that the above query is equivalent to:

```
WITH table_a AS ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30),
     table_b as ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20),
     table_c AS ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT a.id, b.id, c.id
FROM   table_b b inner join table_c c on c.id = b.id right join table_a a on a.id = b.id 
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

, which doesn't require parenthesis.  So if you really want to avoid using parentheses in the `FROM` clause, you usually can do so.  Personally, I prefer the `LEFT JOIN` method with parentheses instead of a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: That query makes sense and explains why parentheses can help.  I'd still like to find something in the documentation diagrams or BNF descriptions that imply this is valid syntax.  Normally the syntax diagrams are helpful and accurate.

Comment: Brackets are valid around a join clause but the [`SELECT` syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDDCHGF) does not indicate that they are valid around a table reference (which is what is asked about in the question).

Comment: Just for curiosity, you can write the exactly the same SQL without the parenthesys and this will still work. 
`WITH table_a AS ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30),
     table_b as ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20),
     table_c AS ( SELECT rownum id FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT a.id, b.id, c.id
FROM   table_a a left join  table_b b inner join table_c c ON c.id = b.id  ON b.id = a.id 
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
`

Answer (score 3):

According to my reading of the [syntax diagram for a SELECT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126863), putting parentheses around a table reference in a SELECT statement is not allowed. As to whether or not Oracle might "fix" things in a way that would make this invalid, I have no way of knowing but I consider it unlikely. YMMV.

Best of luck.

### EDIT

Just for fun I thought I'd put down my reading of the syntax diagram:

As other have noted, parentheses *are* allowed around a `join_clause`, but `dual a` is not a `join_clause`. Rather, it is a `query_table_expression` which is part of a `table_reference`. `dual a` cannot be a `join_clause` - to be such it would have to be followed by an `inner_join_clause` (e.g. `INNER JOIN`) or an `outer_join_clause` (e.g. `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`), which it is not. Per the syntax diagram parentheses are not allowed around a `query_table_expression` *unless* the `query_table_expression` is preceded by `ONLY`, and in OP's query `dual a` is not preceded by `ONLY`. Thus I conclude that per the Oracle syntax diagrams `( ( (dual a) ) )` is not syntactically correct; however, the database seems to disagree. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Additional to *join_clause* the *subquery* may be [nested](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126436).

So this is perfect valid syntax

```
 (((select * from dual)));
```

This provides the clue to the validity of the synax of the questioned query.

```
 select * from (((dual)));
```

Starting with the [select](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126436) we go to query_block

`select --> subquery --> query_block`

`query_block` expands to

```
SELECT * FROM table_reference
```

From `table_reference` we step down to (nested) `subquery`, which can be further nested.

`table_reference --> query_table_expression --> ( subquery )`

So keep expanding `subquery` to get required nesting and finaly choose `TABLE` as the expansion of the [query_table_expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img_text/query_table_expression.htm)

But as MT0 and others noted, this unfortunately don't lead to the e3xpected result. The maximal *legal* query is

```
select * from (((select * from dual)));
```

Comment: You can get from `table_reference -> query_table_expression -> ( subquery )` but you can't carry on and do `subquery -> query_table_expression -> table`. So `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table_name )` is valid but `SELECT * FROM ( table_name )` is not (which is what the question asked about).

Comment: @MT0 [query_table_expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img_text/query_table_expression.htm) expands fine to `table`

Comment: But `subquery` doesn't expand to `query_table_expression` and will, instead, expand to `query_block` which is the entire `SELECT ... FROM ...` statement. So, as I said before, `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table_name )` is valid but `SELECT * FROM ( table_name )` is not.

Comment: @MT0 that was it! Thanks for pointing to my tgought fault! I updated the answer.