# Oracle SQL Language Reference Outer Join Clause Documentation Error?

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, left-join

The Oracle 19 SQL Language Reference Documentation does not seem to allow for either of the following syntax, but yet is valid.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B
    INNER JOIN C
    ON B.b_id = C.b_id
  ON A.a_id = C.a_id
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN (B
    INNER JOIN C
    ON B.b_id = C.b_id)
  ON A.a_id = C.a_id
```

Reasons for suspecting the documentation is incorrect:

1. The inner join portion is not a valid [table_reference::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126863) within the [outer_join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABBCHJA), per the documentation.
2. The [outer_join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABBCHJA) does allow for the option of *not* specifying an `ON condition`, and the [join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDIJFDJ) does allow for an [inner_cross_join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABCGEDH) to immediately follow; however, the syntax diagrams offer no path back to adding the final `ON condition`.
3. Care is taken in other places within the Syntax Diagrams to show when and where parenthesis can be used.  The parenthesis usage as displayed in the second example is valid, but not documented as such in the documentation.

It seems the syntax diagram would be more accurate for the [outer_join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABBCHJA) to reference an *option* of either [table_reference::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126863)  or [join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDIJFDJ) and *require* either the `ON condition` or `USING (...)`.

The point about parenthises is admittedly minor, but the point about the optional [join_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDIJFDJ) seems substantive.

**Is this an Oracle SQL Language Reference documentation error?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm...I've definitely seen the first syntax used before, somewhere.  As for the second second syntax, it looks a lot like Access.  Could it be that Oracle also defaults to supporting the ANSI standard if something is not mentioned explicitly?

Comment: Both syntaxes are supported by standard SQL.  I think it is a documentation error possibly in "query_table_expression".  I'm surprised because I always assumed the documentation diagrams were generated automatically from the Oracle parser.

Comment: This is kind of similar to my old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34754948/409172). The SQL Language Reference is a great resource but not 100% accurate.

Comment: I don't see that the diagrams allow nested join clauses with or without parentheses, which standard SQL does & apparently Oracle. Presumably the diagrams are wrong. Notice also how the non-outer join diagrams properly express required, disallowed & optional on & using, but the outer diagram doesn't. Compare to Oracle's MySQL grammar, which allows nesting with & without parentheses & even uses table_factor vs _reference to show the binding of on/using with innermost join. But don't expect grammars to reflect semantics; such are often not good implementation grammars & the latter get published.